# Access VBA dump recordset into an existing table

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a recordset and a table, both in exactly the same format. What is the syntax to dump everything in the recordset to the table? This seems to be a very simple procedure but somehow I can't find any useful information online.

Edit1: to clarify, the recordset is obtained from Table A, now I want to dump it into Table B (which is empty). Table A and B have exactly the same format.

Edit2: I am working in Access.

here is the code I used to open the recordset:

```
Set Table_B_rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Table_B")
```

I didn't make any changes to the recordset.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't do this with recordsets, but with SQL by running an INSERT INTO query.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO TableB SELECT * FROM TableA " & _
                  "WHERE <same conditions you used to open the recordset>"
```

If there is no condition, it's simply

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table_B SELECT * FROM Table_A"
```

Comment: do I have to close the recordset first?

Comment: Depends on its type - for `dbOpenSnapshot` it doesn't matter, for `dbOpenDynaset` I would close it first. Perhaps the question is: what did you do with the recordset?

Comment: yes. also seems like your code has syntax error? 
I am not good with SQL sorry

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code where you open the recordset (and what you do with it).

Comment: Added. Basically I just want to move all the records in table B to table A